# How to email user after inserting the username in database in WordPress

Tags: wpdb, wp-mail

I have following piece of code, which inserts usernames and other details of users in the database. After inserting the usernames I want to email them using `wp_mail();`. I am unable to do so. How can I do this?

```
$member_details->user_login = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_login'] );
$member_details->user_role = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['user_role'] );
$member_details->status = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST['status'] );

$member_details_encode = wp_json_encode( $member_details );

  global $wpdb;

  $member_result = $wpdb->insert( 'wpxa_project_members',

         array( 

              'project_id'     => $_SESSION['project_id'],
              'author_id'      => $post_author,
              'member_details' => $member_details_encode

              ),

         array( 

              '%d',
              '%d',
              '%s'

      )

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$member_details->user_login` is already a user in the `wp_users` table, then you could use the following to get their email address:

`$user = get_user_by( $member_details->user_login, 'login' );`

From there, you have the user's email address and can use `wp_mail()` to email them:

```
$subject = "My email subject";
$message = "My message body...";
wp_mail( $user->user_email, $subject, $message );
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us see what code you are trying.  Assuming that the hook you have bound that function to is firing, you would insert this into your function, assuming you want to email the author.

```
wp_mail($to = $post_author, $subject = 'This is the subject', $message = 'This is the message');
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

Edit:

```
$user = get_userdatabylogin($member_details->user_login);
$user_id = $user->ID;
wp_mail($user_id, 'This is the subject', 'This is the message');
```

Comment: I want all the users which are inserted into database through my code.. Actually I have created a dynamic add / remove fields in which I write usernames of the users. I want to mail them once inserted.

Comment: Check my edit above

Comment: How can we mail through user_id... And how to get the emails of users in array.. Thanks LearntoExcel

Comment: wp_mail uses the user_id, you don't need the email.  You can get the user_id using the code above.

Comment: That's absolutely incorrect. wp_mail does not use user_id - so yes, you do need the email.  Additionally, `get_userdatabylogin()` is a deprecated function and should no longer be used. You should be using `get_user_by()` instead.